# Java: How To Create Variables For User Imputed Words

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that asks the user for their name, age, and their favourite type of food. The program will then repeat what they have imputed. Please note that the program is not finished yet. Once I write this particular piece of code, I get an error. Please excuse my lack of intelligence when it comes to programming. I am an extremely new learner.

Here is the code: `name = Test.nextDouble();`

To help you better understand the program, here is my workspace:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    class HelloProgram {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner Test = new Scanner(System.in);
        double name, age, favfood;
        System.out.println("Hello there! Before we start, I would like to ask you a few questions!");
        System.out.println("Let us start with your name. What is it?");
        name = Test.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(name);

    }
}
```

Once I try to run the program, then type in my name, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at HelloProgram.main(HelloProgram.java:9)
```

As I said before, I do believe that this is caused by using the "newDouble()" part. Is this because "Double" does not support words?

I would appreciate if someone could **explain** to me why this doesn't work and help me **fix** it. Thank you.

Comment: I think you should work on your Java basics. Read some beginner's tutorial.

Comment: You should probably use a `String` instead of double here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes "Double" does not support words. Double or double are floating point numeric types and accept numbers only. If you want to accept text, use Scanner's other methods such as `next()` or `nextLine()`, which both accept Strings, and make the name and favfood variables Strings:

```
public static void main (String args[]){
    Scanner test = new Scanner (System.in);
    String name, favfood;
    double age;
    System.out.println("Hello there! Before we start, I would like to ask you a few questions!");
    System.out.print("Let us start with your name. What is it? ");
    name = test.nextLine();
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Other recommendations to make it easier for you and others (us!) to understand your code:

- Learn and follow Java naming conventions, including giving variables, like "test" names that start with a lower case letter, and classes names that start with an upper case letter.
- Code indentation is very important in keeping track of which code belongs to which block. All nested blocks should be indented 4 spaces, for example -- your main method should be indented, but its not.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy response. I would never have even thought to add two different variable types ;)

Answer (score 0):

A `double` is used for floating point values. I am not good at explaining but you would need to use a `String` for text values and an `int` for whole numbers.

Comment: *A double is always a integer like value* No, it is not. `double` != `int`.

Comment: I looked it up properly, a double is used for precise values.

Comment: I'd word that differently since doubles are like floats in that they hold values for floating-point (non-integer) numbers, and double is *more* precise than float, but is still not a "precise value". For high precision you'd  use BigDecimal, but you'd also have to pay the costs of this type -- larger memory footprint and slower calculation speeds.